# Monitorar tags recentemente carregadas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, script

meu cenario é o seguinte, tenho um menu (class="menu") onde qualquer link que for clicado nele é aberto em uma div ( div id="conteudo")

o problema esta que os links que abrem dentro da div conteudo mesmo utilizando a classe menu nos links eles nao abrem dentro da propria div? alguma ideia do que pode ser?

```
 $('.menu').on('click', function () {
 $('#conteudo').load(this.href);
 return false;
 });

  --> esses links carrega dentro da div conteudo OK
  <a class="menu" href="pg1.php"></a>
  <a class="menu" href="pg2.php"></a>
  <a class="menu" href="pg3.php"></a>

  <div id="conteudo" > 
  --> esse link nao carrega a pagina 4 dentro da propria div
  <a class="menu" href="pg4.php"></a>
  </div>
```

Posso estar enganado mais creio que o jquery não enxerga a classe recentemente carregada dentro da div por isso ele não abre dentro dela propria. alguma solução para isso?

Comment: Utilize `$('#conteudo').on('click', '.menu a', function () {
 $('#conteudo').load(this.href);
 return false;
 });`

Comment: nossa que obvil, quando se esta dentro do projeto não vê as coisas simples, mais de alguma maneira ele não reconheceu o (.menu a)  somente reconheceu a classe sem o indicativo do link (.menu)

Comment: Verdade. Acabei me equivocando com o `.menu a`